# Rewrite JSON structure and include an EACH loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, rendering, each

I have a list of shows in a database that need to be output in a certain JSON style in order to work with Polymaps.

Part of this includes the need to iterate over one section in order to create a list of points. I'm pretty certain that this needs to be achieved using :include in the render :json => @results bit of the code.

Here's the code as it stands:

```
def gigs

  @gigs = Show.where(:displayname => "Vans Warped Tour 2011")

  @giggage = [{
  :type => "FeatureCollection",
  :features => [
    @gigs.each do |gig|
      :type => "feature",
      :geometry => {
        :coordinates => [
          gig['lng'], 
          gig['lat']
        ],
       :type => "Point"
      },
      :properties => gig
    end
    ]
  }]

  render :json => @giggage
end
```

There's an each loop inside a hash which I know you can't do, but that's the best way to illustrate what I'm going for, I'm going in circles on this.

I did try this which got me some of the way there, but only returned the one result because of the structure of the loop:

```
def gigs
  @gigs = Show.where(:displayname => "Vans Warped Tour 2011")
  @gigs.each do |gig|
    @gigs_to_render = {
      :type => "FeatureCollection",
      :features => [
          :type => "feature",
          :geometry => {
            :coordinates => [
              gig['lng'], 
              gig['lat']
            ],
           :type => "Point"
          },
          :properties => gig
     ]
    } 
end
render :json => @gigs_to_render
```

end

Thanks for your help! Anyone. Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as it stands should be very close to working. Just change `each` to `map` and surround the body of the block in curlies so it all gets returned as a hash for each gig.