# Mapbox fitBounds fits map to markers, but doesn't render tiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geojson, mapbox

I am building a ruby on rails app that creates a unique map for each Product model in the database and inserts it into a slide of a flexslider slideshow.

This is working perfectly for json requests that only contain 1 marker. However, when json requests are made with 2 markers, the map's tiles do not render (but both markers are displayed and fit to view).

The rendering issue is solved by moving the "map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());" into the featureLayer.on('click') function. But I need the functionality to fitBounds after the JSON is loaded rather than on click.

The error I get in the browswer console is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined" I have searched dozens of threads for help with this, but cannot solve it. I am a newbie to all of this, so your help would be greatly appreciated.

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
function initProductMap(product) {

var map;
map = L.mapbox.map(document.getElementById(product), 'jasonpearson.ha88l84b');

    var featureLayer;
    featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('/products/' + product + '.json').addTo(map);
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    map.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomright');

    featureLayer.on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());

        featureLayer.on('click', function(e) {
        e.layer.unbindPopup();
        window.open(e.layer.feature.properties.url, '_self');
        });

    });

    $('ul.slides li').show();
    map.invalidateSize();
};
```

MY RAILS CONTROLLER

```
  def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@geojson = Array.new

@product.producers.each do |producer|
  @geojson << {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [        
      {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [producer.longitude, producer.latitude]
        },
        properties: {
          name: producer.name,
          'marker-color' => '#9f3335',
          'marker-symbol' => 'circle',
          'marker-size' => 'medium',
          url: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.producer_path(producer)          
        }
      }
    ]
  }    
end
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual JSON being output by your Rails code? It's very likely that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I realized my output was duplicating 'FeatureCollection' in my geojson. 

That led me to this thread, and eventually the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513627/rewrite-json-structure-and-include-an-each-loop-in-rails